# Please make it an aim to vote on questions, even if they aren't your own

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, recent-activity

In our early days we voted 450 times on 45 posts (10 votes/post), and this shrunk to 337 votes on 55 posts (about 6 votes/post) in July, and seems to have shrunk to nearly 0 votes in the last couple days.

[image]

**This is going to create an imbalance on our site.**

New users with equally good questions compared to earlier questions, will unfortunately have unfairly low scores on their questions, and likewise their reputation and ability to participate in the site will be deflated unfairly.

Only about 45 days ago there was a moderator at the Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange who pointed out that our last 10 questions all had at least 7 upvotes:

[image]

I am sad to see that now **zero of our last 10 questions have** 7 upvotes (we have to go back to the 12th most recent question to find one with at least 7 upvotes):

[image]

On 12 February we set a record for the lowest number of votes we've ever made in a day: A grand total of 6. **This is going to do more harm than good to our community if this trend continues.** We have more users and more total posts than ever, so our total number of votes/day should be going up, not down to record low numbers.

**Please** try to open more questions than just the question you came to this site to ask, and if you believe the question belongs on this site, then upvote it. **If you don't believe the question belongs on this site, please leave a comment to let the user know that rather than downvoting.**

**If you would like to help this community survive, try to get yourself on our [list of top voters!](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)**

Comment: I definitely agree that this is important and its one of the easiest ways a user can participate and help the site grow. From the plots, it looks like the the number of votes is highly correlated with the number of new posts. If someone only goes through the newest posts, they might only be able to give out 1-5 for a question/answer. But with more users, I would expect that we would see more voting. Hopefully people aren't filtering the questions they view too much. With the site still being fairly young, it shouldn't be necessary to ignore certain tags.

Comment: +1 to the comment @Tyberius. There's qualitatively a correlation between new votes and new posts, but it goes from 10 votes/post (in the early stages), to 6 votes/post (during the question spree in July), and now recently we hit a record-low for voting, so if new votes are proportional to number of new posts, the proportionality constant is getting smaller.

Comment: A more worrying thing is this: the top voters are people who have been around since the beginning, so if we've already voted for questions that were asked up to February, then now we would only be voting on questions that are new in February (as we see them surface). However the new users would ideally be voting on not just new posts, but also previous posts!!! This means votes/day should be proportional to the total # of users, and *not* just to the number of new posts/day. **Votes/day should be going up as the number of users goes up, not a constant like posts/day roughly is.**